# Trying to append/push object to returned array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a checkUser function,

```
module.exports.checkUser = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        iUser.find({ userName: userData.userName })
        .exec()
        .then((users) => {
```

Which returns an array of size `1`, with one user, accessible through `users[0].(...)`

To `users[0].loginHistory`, I need to push the object,

```
 {dateTime: (new Date()).toString(), userAgent: userData.userAgent}
```

I am using MongoDB, and was wondering if I can do something like,

```
users[0].loginHistory.push({dateTime: (new Date()).toString(), userAgent: userData.userAgent});
```

Where `userData.userAgent` was defined with `get('User-Agent);`

My schema,

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    "userName": {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    "email": String,
    "password": String,
    "loginHistory": {
        "userAgent": String,
        "dateTime": Date
    }
  });
```

Clearly the `push()` JS method isnt working for me. Am I doing something wrong? When `checkUser` finished processing, after the `push()`, it expects to replace the document in the MongoDB collection with the updated userHistory,

```
users[0].loginHistory.push({dateTime: (new Date()).toString(), userAgent: userData.userAgent});
    iUser.update({ 
        userName: users[0].userName},
        { $set: { loginHistory: users[0].loginHistory } 
    })
    .exec()
    .then(() => {
         resolve(users[0]);
     })
```

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON object is a `Date` type, it won't have `push` as a member function. Can you convert `userSchema.loginHistory.dateTime` to an Array? Then you can work with it like you want (i.e. as a list).

Answer (score 0):

`loginHistory` is an object in your model but you are pushing into it in your code as if it was an array. 
Beside, `dateTime` field is a date so no need to convert it to a string. 
If you need loginHistory to be a collection, change the field to:

```
"loginHistory": [{
    "userAgent": String,
    "dateTime": Date
}]
```

and then use your assignment (no need of toString()):

```
users[0].loginHistory.push({ dateTime: new Date(), userAgent: userData.userAgent});
```

If this not what you want, or you can't change the model, you need to change the loginHistory assignment in your code to:

```
users[0].loginHistory = { dateTime: new Date(), userAgent: userData.userAgent };
```